# Why is `to_thread` faster than `create_task` in python asyncio?

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous, async-await, python-asyncio

I have a blocking function that calls an REST endpoint and returns some result. Let's simulate that as below:

```py
import random, time, asyncio
def test_func(x):
    time.sleep(2*random.random())
    return x
```

I tried to use python `asyncio` to turn this blocking call into async non-blocking calls. I tried two implementations:

- first:

```py
class Output:
    output = None

def test_func_thread(x, out: Output):
    out.output = test_func(x)

async def imp1():
    coroutines = []
    scores = []
    for _ in range(10):
        scores.append(Output())
        coroutines.append(asyncio.to_thread(test_func_thread, _, scores[-1]))
    for coroutine in asyncio.as_completed(coroutines):
        await coroutine
    return [_.output for _ in scores]
```

- second:

```py
async def async_score(x):
    return test_func(x)

async def imp2():
    tasks = []
    results = []
    for _ in range(10):
        tasks.append(asyncio.create_task(async_score(_)))

    for t in tasks:
        if not t.done():
            await t
        results.append(t.result())
    return results
```

And also the sync blocking version:

```py
def imp3():
    result = []
    for _ in range(10):
        result.append(test_func(_))
    return result
```

And the running time of each:

```py
print(asyncio.run(imp1()))
> [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
%timeit asyncio.run(imp1())
> 1 loops, best of 5: 1.45 s per loop

print(asyncio.run(imp2()))
> [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
%timeit asyncio.run(imp2())
> 1 loops, best of 5: 7.11 s per loop

print(imp3())
> [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
%timeit imp3()
> 1 loops, best of 5: 8.66 s per loop
```

I was expecting `imp2()` and `imp1()` would have similar performance but `imp2()` actually is closer to the sync blocking version and using `asyncio` does not help much. I'm obviously not familiar with `asyncio`, so here are my questions:

1. Why is `imp2()` behaving like sync blocking version?
2. What's a pythonic implementation for use case like this?
3. If `imp2()` is more pythonic, how do I make it perform like `imp1()`?
4. For `imp1()`, I had to make a `class Output` trick to keep the return results in the same order as the function call order and this does not seem pythonic to me. Are there better ways to do something like this?

Thanks!

---

Update:

For `imp2`, I also tried the following implementation:

```py
async def imp2():
    tasks = [async_score(_) for _ in range(10)]
    results = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
    return results
```

But it still behaves like a sync and blocking call that does not have any performance gain.

Comment: Blocking functions don't stop being blocking just because you gave them their own task.

Comment: so what's best way to implement for this use case?

Comment: If possible, rewrite your blocking function to use actually asynchronous calls.

Comment: i'm afraid that's not possible. it's a network i/o bound blocking call. i'm hoping to make it async in my python code.

Comment: Being network I/O bound doesn't mean it has to be blocking. If it's a library out of your control that doesn't provide an async interface, then you'll have to run the call in another thread, but if the problem is just the network I/O, there are plenty of async ways to do that.

Comment: right. i don't have control over the network call in this case.

Comment: If you're not able to asynchronously do the network calls (see https://www.python-httpx.org/async/) then you won't find any benefit in using asyncio. You might be better of just using something like a ThreadPoolExecutor https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html 
If you need some help let me know.